# JPG file loaded into the node canvas module loses quality after operations and export

Tags: javascript, canvas, todataurl, image-quality, node-canvas

I am using the node canvas implementation
https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas

I use it to cut a jpg export of a newsletter design into slices and generate an image based HTML template that is email friendly.
Essentially it's just slices from the source at around 550px based on my emailing requirements.

The problem is that when I load the source jpg file, I see some loss in the exported slices.
Here is an example:

[Source vs exported example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE3cr.png)

As you can see the version on the right (the source - jpg) is somewhat crisper and has better quality than what the node canvas has processed.

I'm already using the export jpg at full quality in all my toDataUrl calls, as opposed to the 0.92 in the spec. I am using the loadImage function that node canvas provides, would it be possible to lose quality there?

`this.writeImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0), i);`

Additionaly, I already beefed up the quality settings on the context:

```
    ctx.patternQuality = 'best';
    ctx.quality = 'best';
    ctx.antialias = 'subpixel';
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false
```

I'm thinking maybe I didn't use those settings above correctly? Or perhaps, missed one?

One of the ideas flying around is to blow up the source at 2x, and then resize when processing, in order to maintain the original jpeg quality.

My question is, what can I do to prevent any loss of quality when processing? It doesn't make sense to get a lower quality image at the end of the process with all the steps applied, and yet...

Thank you very much,
Dragos.

Later edit:

I'm actually asking the question wrong, the source I'm using is actually PNG, exactly because I wanted big quality in my jpeg exports.
Exports will clearly not be as good as the original PNG, but I obtained the source in JPG form and still it had losses vs the *potential* JPG I might use, but technically I'm cutting from a PNG.

Comment: This is not a solution and it is unclear what the source of the degradation is. JPEG compresses using discrete wavelet transforms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000#Wavelet_transform. Wavelets cover an 8 by 8 pixel area. You can not just cut a JPG at an arbitrary x, y (top left) as it changes the position of the wavelet samples making it impossible to reproduce the original wavelets. You must cut (top left) at multiples of 8 to have a chance of maintaining original quality. Also it looks like you are using a pattern to render the image, dont, render it using `ctx.drawImage`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 

I'm definitely using ctx.drawImage for cropping.

Cutting in 8px multiples might put a dent in my business use case, however, based on what you said: 

What if I don't use drawImage to do the the cutting and simply prepare an empty canvas, and then, instead of cutting and cropping with drawImage, I simply place the WHOLE source on this canvas and use a translation to get me over the area of the source I wanted to see. Sort of like a stencil if you will. That would mean the whole image is still there when I run toDataUrl, but I only see the part I want to see?

Comment: `toDataUrl` is performed on the canvas which is independent of the context and is thus not effected by any transformation

Comment: I realized I asked the question a bit wrong, I added more info, am I safe from the the 8 by 8 thing? 

My second idea of cropping via exporting would not work either, you say?